# Setting value for dataframe column from another dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one dataframe

```
#Around 100000 rows
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':    [ 'Apple is healthy',  'Potato is round', 'Apple might be green'],
                   'category': ["","", ""],
                   })
```

A second dataframe

```
#Around 3000 rows
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'keyword':    [ 'Apple ',  'Potato'],
                   'category': ["fruit","vegetable"],
                   })
```

The required result

```
#Around 100000 rows
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':    [ 'Apple is healthy',  'Potato is round', 'Apple might be green'],
                   'category': ["fruit","vegetable", "fruit"],
                   })
```

I tried this currently

```
df.set_index('text')
df_2.set_index('keyword')
df.update(df_2)
```

The result is

```
text    category
Apple is healthy    fruit
Potato is round vegetable
Apple might be green
```

AS you can see it does not add category for last row. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need assign back output from [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), because not inplace operation like [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html), for matching is used [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) by column `df_2["keyword"]`:

```
df = df.set_index(df['text'].str.extract(f'({"|".join(df_2["keyword"])})', expand=False))
df_2 = df_2.set_index('keyword')
print (df)
                        text category
text                                 
Apple       Apple is healthy         
Potato       Potato is round         
Apple   Apple might be green  



df.update(df_2)
print (df)
                        text   category
text                                   
Apple       Apple is healthy      fruit
Potato       Potato is round  vegetable
Apple   Apple might be green      fruit
```

If need add only one column use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
s = df['text'].str.extract(f'({"|".join(df_2["keyword"])})', expand=False)
df['category'] = s.map(df_2.set_index(['keyword'])['category'])
print (df)
                   text   category
0      Apple is healthy      fruit
1       Potato is round  vegetable
2  Apple might be green      fruit
```